# Disable queries on table while updating

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a pl/sql script that clears (via `delete from` statement) and populates several depended tables like this:

```
delete from table-A
insert into table-A values(...)
delete from table-B
insert into table-B values(...)
```

These operations require ~ 10 seconds to complete and I'd like to stop all sql queries that try to read data from table-A or table-B while tables are updating. These queries should stop and continue execution when table-A and table-B are completely updated.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why would you do that? As far the delete/insert is in a transaction(no commit between them) the user would not see the "between" states. There is no dirty read in Oracle, if this is what you want to prevent.

Comment: The only way to stop anyone **reading** the tables is to revoke their SELECT privilege on it. as @FlorinGhita says, there is no need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, Oracle's basic concurrency model is that writers do not block readers and readers do not block writers.  You can't stop a simple `select` from running.  Your queries will see the data as of the SCN that they started executing (assuming that you're using the default `read committed` transaction isolation level) so they will have a consistent view of the data before your updates started.

You could potentially acquire a custom named lock using [`dbms_lock.request`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#i1002556).  You would need to acquire this lock before running your updates and every session that queries the tables would also need to acquire the lock before it starts to query the tables.  That will, obviously, decrease the scalability of your application but it will accomplish what you appear to be asking for.  Presumably, the sessions doing queries can acquire the lock in shared mode while the session doing the updates would need to acquire it in exclusive mode.